# How to return data if value does not exist in the nested array of objects using Higher order functions

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have a Nested array of objects like below:

```
let a = [{
    title: "A123",
    book: "A",
    tags: [{
        key: "Romantic",
        ID: 1
    }, {
        key: "Sad",
        ID: 2
    },{
        key: "Strange",
        ID: 3
    }]
}, {
    title: "B123",
    book: "B",
    tags: [{
        key: "Parody",
        ID: 1
    }, {
        key: "Romantic",
        ID: 2
    },{
        key: "Happy",
        ID: 3
    }]
}, {
    title: "C123",
    book: "C",
    tags: [{
        key: "Dark",
        ID: 1
    }, {
        key: "Science Fiction",
        ID: 2
    }]
},  {
    title: "D123",
    book: "D",
    tags: [{
        key: "New Life",
        ID: 1
    }, {
        key: "Science Fiction",
        ID: 2
    }]
}]
```

Now I am trying to get the output of those objects which does not contain the tags as 'Romantic'.

** Expected Output:**

```
{
    title: "C123",
    book: "C",
    tags: [{
        key: "Dark",
        ID: 1
    }, {
        key: "Science Fiction",
        ID: 2
    }]
},  {
    title: "D123",
    book: "D",
    tags: [{
        key: "New Life",
        ID: 1
    }, {
        key: "Science Fiction",
        ID: 2
    }]
}
```

I have tried the below from my end but it is returning all the elements. Is there a way to achieve the expected output?

```
a.filter( (ele) => ele.tags.filter( (eachTags) => eachTags.key !== 'Romantic'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead of the 2nd `filter`:

```
a.filter(book => book.tags.every(tag => tag.key !== "Romantic"));
```

Which is saying filter the array and exclude a book where any tag is `Romantic`.

Example:

```js
let a = [{
    title: "A123",
    book: "A",
    tags: [{
        key: "Romantic",
        ID: 1
    }, {
        key: "Sad",
        ID: 2
    },{
        key: "Strange",
        ID: 3
    }]
}, {
    title: "B123",
    book: "B",
    tags: [{
        key: "Parody",
        ID: 1
    }, {
        key: "Romantic",
        ID: 2
    },{
        key: "Happy",
        ID: 3
    }]
}, {
    title: "C123",
    book: "C",
    tags: [{
        key: "Dark",
        ID: 1
    }, {
        key: "Science Fiction",
        ID: 2
    }]
},  {
    title: "D123",
    book: "D",
    tags: [{
        key: "New Life",
        ID: 1
    }, {
        key: "Science Fiction",
        ID: 2
    }]
}];

let notRomantic = a.filter(book => book.tags.every(tag => tag.key !== "Romantic"));

console.log(notRomantic);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you could use `Array.prototype.some()`:

```js
let a = [
 {title: "A123",book: "A",tags: [{key: "Romantic",ID: 1}, {key: "Sad",ID: 2},{key: "Strange",ID: 3}]},
 {title: "B123",book: "B",tags: [{key: "Parody",ID: 1}, {key: "Romantic",ID: 2},{key: "Happy",ID: 3}]},
 {title: "C123",book: "C",tags: [{key: "Dark",ID: 1}, {key: "Science Fiction",ID: 2}]},
 {title: "D123",book: "D",tags: [{key: "New Life",ID: 1}, {key: "Science Fiction",ID: 2}]}]
 
 console.log(a.filter(o=>!o.tags.some(t=>t.key==="Romantic")))
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this result using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
const result = a.filter((obj) => !obj.tags.some((o) => o.key === "Romantic"));
```

```js
let a = [
  {
    title: "A123",
    book: "A",
    tags: [
      {
        key: "Romantic",
        ID: 1,
      },
      {
        key: "Sad",
        ID: 2,
      },
      {
        key: "Strange",
        ID: 3,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "B123",
    book: "B",
    tags: [
      {
        key: "Parody",
        ID: 1,
      },
      {
        key: "Romantic",
        ID: 2,
      },
      {
        key: "Happy",
        ID: 3,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "C123",
    book: "C",
    tags: [
      {
        key: "Dark",
        ID: 1,
      },
      {
        key: "Science Fiction",
        ID: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    title: "D123",
    book: "D",
    tags: [
      {
        key: "New Life",
        ID: 1,
      },
      {
        key: "Science Fiction",
        ID: 2,
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = a.filter((obj) => !obj.tags.some((o) => o.key === "Romantic"));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```